# Examining ASCII

Tags: c, gdb, ascii

How can I get the [`ASCII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) representation of hexadecimal values in the memory by examining in [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)?

The gdb command `x/[repeatCount] [memoryAddress]` gives me hexadecimal 32-bit values starting at `memoryAddress` `repeatCount` times but I want the readable text/String which is represented by this data. How do I do that? [This](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_55.html) page doesn't seem to tell.

For instance I get the following by examining:

```
0x41414141
```

What I want to see instead or as well is this:

```
AAAA
```

Like an ordinary [Hex <-> ASCII converter](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, I need to use the `format letter` `s` for `String`.

```
x/[repeatCount]s [memoryAddress]
```

Found by typing

```
help x
```

and reading the help documentation. <_<